# How would you use map to find a specific value from each object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

I'm new to angular and I'm attempting to call an API like https://swapi.co/ to get just the name of each person from the array of people objects and put their name in a dropdown menu. For this project, I need to use .map() to create the values for the dropdown. I've tried looking at the angular documentation but I'm honestly very confused and could use some guidance.

**service.ts**

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StarwarsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPeoples() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/  ');
  }

  getPlanets() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/  ');
  }

  getStarships() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/starships/  ');
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { PlanetsComponent } from './planets/planets.component';
import { StarshipsComponent } from './starships/starships.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    PlanetsComponent,
    StarshipsComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**body/component.ts**

```
import { StarwarsService } from '../starwars.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.scss']
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private starwarsService: StarwarsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.starwarsService.getPeoples().subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);

    });
  }

}
```

**body.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/people" routerLink="/people" routerLinkActive="active">People</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/planets" routerLink="/planets" routerLinkActive="active">Planets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/starships" routerLink="/starships" routerLinkActive="active">Starships</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

  <select>
    <option></option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has some structural directives that will help in rendering lists. One such directive is `*ngFor`. Read more [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf).

You'll need to store the response of the api on a property on the component class.

```js
import { StarwarsService } from '../starwars.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.scss']
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {

  peoples: unknown[];

  constructor(private starwarsService: StarwarsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.starwarsService.getPeoples().subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);
      this.peoples = results.results;
    });
  }
}
```

We assign the `results` which contains the data from the api to the `this.peoples` property, so that we can use it in the template.

In the `template` we can use the `*ngFor` directive to list the `peoples`

```html
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let people of peoples">
    {{people.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: i tried this just now and i got this error  ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: because the api returns the list of people in the results property of the results. updated the answer. change `this.peoples = results.results`